# cout перевести в printf

Tags: c++, c

Всем привет, подскажите как будет выглядеть отрывок этого кода c++ на обычном си.

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cout << "|" << table[i][j] << "|";
    }
```

Comment: нужно вывести массив, через printf

Comment: `printf("|%d|", table[i][j]);`, где вместо `d` следует указать [подходящий](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) спецификатор преобразования в зависимости от типа элементов массива `table`.

Comment: Чтобы было красиво, добавьте в формат ширину поля, например, `printf("|%8d|", table[i][j]);` будет выводить числа в поле шириной 8 символов